# Run C++ code in mac without Xcode, and use custom header bits/stdc++.h

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

Trying to run C++ on Vscode on a Mac, but the stdc++.h library is not found.
I want to setup bits/stdc++.h instead of the custom header of clang++.

fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found.

It will help if someone give me the c_cpp_properties.json file and settings

Comment: Please read ["Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdc++.h setup on mac (without xcode)

Assuming that you've installed the homebrew and C/C++ compiler extension.
Then follow the steps. As the bits/stdc++ is a GNU GCC extension,
where OSX uses the clang compiler.

- brew install gcc
- gcc --version
- go to the /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include directory
  (go to finder, type command+shift+g, then paste the directory name)
- create a folder named bits inside this directory and then copy the stdc++.h file from this
  github link (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h).
- create a file naming bits/stdc++.h inside the bits folder and paste the code copied from the github link into bits/stdc++.h file,
  then save it.
- then initially after restarting vscode, some user get a error message as
  some library is deprecated in stdc++.h.
  for dismissing that error, you should add the gcc library's path to c_cpp_properties.json file's includePath.
- ("/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/include/c++/12",
  "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/include/c++/12/x86_64-apple-darwin21")

You can get this path by hovering on your #include file on code too.
add these two path to your includePath section inside of C_cpp_properties.json file.
make sure your compilerPath is "/usr/bin/clang"

I am giving the c_cpp_properties.json initial file here for your understanding.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/include/c++/12",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/include/c++/12/x86_64-apple-darwin21"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Would be better to recommend *never* to include that header in the first place.